# Getting the linecount in a collection of files?

Tags: excel, vba

Everytime I run this and try to paste it it will just keep incrementing the lineCount for each line it reads.

I want to grab the unique lineCount for each varFile and store it in an array.

How can I do this?

```
'Collect all data from audit templates
RecursiveDir colFiles, path, "*.xlsm", True
For Each varFile In colFiles
    reportRow = 2
    Set reportBook = Workbooks.Open(varFile)
    Set cooSummary = reportBook.Sheets("Audit")
    reportRow = 2
    Do While cooSummary.Cells(reportRow, 1) <> ""
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
        lineNum = lineNum + 1
        With cooSummary
            scanDate = FileDateTime(varFile)
            scanned = lineCount
            auditor = .Cells(1, 2)
        End With
        ReDim Preserve reportArray(3, lineNum)
        reportArray(0, lineNum) = scanDate
        reportArray(1, lineNum) = scanned
        reportArray(2, lineNum) = auditor
        reportRow = reportRow + 1
    Loop
reportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next varFile

'Paste data into Scan Sheet
For lineNum = 1 To UBound(reportArray, 2)
    With scanSheet
        .Cells(baseRow, 1) = reportArray(0, lineNum) 'Date Scanned
        .Cells(baseRow, 2) = reportArray(1, lineNum) 'Scanned
        .Cells(baseRow, 3) = reportArray(2, lineNum) 'Auditor
        .Cells(baseRow, 4).Formula = "=IF(LEN(C" & baseRow & ")>10,C" & baseRow & ",IF(LEN(C" & baseRow & ")>=5,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(C" & baseRow & "),3)), C" & baseRow & "))" 'Auditor1
        .Cells(baseRow, 5).Formula = "=IF(LEN(C" & baseRow & ")>10,"""",IF(LEN(C" & baseRow & ")>=5,TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(C" & baseRow & "),3)), """"))" 'Auditor 2
        .Cells(baseRow, 6).Formula = "=IF(E" & baseRow & "="""",B" & baseRow & ",B" & baseRow & "/2)" 'Average Scanned
        .Cells(baseRow, 7).Formula = "=IF(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D" & baseRow & ",Summary!A:C,1,0)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(E" & baseRow & ",Summary!A:C,1,0))),""MISSING"",""GOOD"")" 'Auditor CK
    End With
    baseRow = baseRow + 1
Next lineNum
```

Comment: Without testing it looks like you need to reset your lionecount variable for each file, so under for each varfile throw in a linecount = 0

Comment: If you are doing the line number on a workbook by workbook basis you, from the looks of it, would need to relocate the paste data code up to the varFile loop and likely clear it for each iteration.